# Answering with another question for "What do you mean"

Tags: american-english, questions

Is it correct to answer "by what?" for the question: "What do you mean?", like:

- What do you mean?
- By what?
- By doing this... (example)

Is there any better way to answer with a question that sounds more fluently?

Comment: I sometimes  hear Americans say "what do you mean, what do you mean?"

Comment: *By what* is not an answer, but a question to clarify a detail before answering.

Comment: It *is* fluent, but more so in speech, and in context.

Comment: Wa da ya mean, what do I mean?

Comment: "Sorry, can you be more specific./?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is appropriate to use "By what?" as a response to the first question. This usage implies that the second speaker is unsure what the first speaker is referring to. I'd say that the interaction you have written sounds fluent in American English.

If you want a more formal way, you can consider using a full sentence: "What do I mean by what?"